# QTP Consurrent License Usage Information

Tags: licensing, qtp, hp-uft

we have 10 QTP concurrent licence for our team. The QTP software was installed in 20 Machines. The problem is we cannot track the usage of QTP software as a whole. Attimes people will be using QTP tool and few times they many not use. Is their any way to track the QTP tool usage, like in which machine the QTP is opened, what is the current status of QTP in each machine(running, idle,closed,open) etc.

Thanks in Advance :)

Answer (score 3):

Use the 'WLMAdmin.exe' tool.  Check out [this guide](http://www.learnqtp.com/uft-qtp-license-complete-guide/) under the section "How to manage concurrent license servers".  It explains how to obtain it.